# Get JSON data as PHP with Javascript SDK ONLY

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, facebook

I've setup the Facebook Javascript SDK and have that working and displaying the correct information on the page. Also, I've echoed the user into the Firebug console so it displays the Object with all of the user profile information.

*** I do not want to use the PHP SDK since it does not function the same way in regards to login.

Since I have the Object, how can I go about converting this into a PHP array? I have no idea how to use Ajax for this, or if it's required? Totally lost here and any help would be appreciated! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

JS is purely client-side. If you want a PHP arra, you'd have to first convert that JS object to a JSON-encoded string, send it to your PHP script via an AJAX call, and then do a [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) on the string.

Comment: Hey Marc, thanks for the reply! This was exactly the process I've been told, but I have no idea how to accomplish this! :p I've been digging for tutorials, but can't come across anything that makes sense to me.

Comment: jquery can encode an object to json automatically, and has ajax helpers built in: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/